# Is modifying model of JTable allowed while processing TableModelEvent?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am wondering how to implement such behavior, which would let me to delete row from JTable when value in particular column of this row changes to some fixed value.

I tried to do it using TableModelListener but without intended effect. My problem is connected with the fact that, when I modify model while processing UPDATE TableModelEvent then I condemn myself to deal with inconsistency between possibly modified model (Source of event) with the Event itself. In other words events could have been generated based on different state of the model of table.

```
void onTableChanged(TableModelEvent tableModelEvent)
{
    MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)e.getSource();
    if ( e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE){
        MyObject myObject = (MyObject)model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn());
        if ( myObject.getSomeProperty().equals("DELETE ME")){
          model.removeRow(e.getFirstRow()); // does it look like asking for troubles?
        }            
    }
}
```

and now imagine, we have a method which let us update several rows at once.

```
class MyObject {
    private String someProperty;

    //...getters/setters
}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static int SOME_PROPERTY_COL = 1;     
    private final List<MyObject> data;

    public MyTableModel(List<MyObject> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    //...

    void update(int[] modelIndices, String newSomePropertValue)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < modelIndices.length; i++){
            data[modelIndices[i]].setSomeProperty(newSomePropertyValue);
            fireCellUpdated(modelIndices[i], SOME_PROPERTY_COL);
        }
    }
}
```

There is inconsistency in such implementation between rowIndex, colIndex, in TableModelEvent vs state of model at the time of second, and later events received as a result of invoking update(int[], String) method on MyTableModel object.

I believe the problems comes from the fact that, I try to modify source of events while receiving events generated basing on some particular state of this source, but would not that be an issue as well, if e.g whatever event indicating change in the mode was interleaved with model modification, and some other event which was generated based on old state of model?

What I would like to achieve ultimately is implementation which would let me move row from one table to another table basing on value in some column in a table.

So Imagine one of the cell is a combo box, with 2 values, and we have a two tables, when value in a cell changes to table1 then row is transferred from current table to table1. I thought that using TableModelListener would be proper solution, but I can see that modifying model within this method is not a good idea, isn't it?

Comment: No, I wouldn't suggest it's a good idea, you could trigger follow up model events.  It would be more appropriate to perform the operations within the model itself

Comment: That is what I thought, so probably injecting logic responsible for deleting row to setValueAt method of AbstractTableModel, and calling fireTableRowsDeleted()?

Comment: That would be my first guess. You might consider just adding a `deleteRow` method into the model implementation, but that comes downs to needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model.removeRow(e.getFirstRow()); // does it look like asking for troubles?
```

Wrap the code in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

Now the code will be added to the end of the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) so the table processing and table model listener processing can finish normally before the row deletion is done.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        model.removeRow(e.getFirstRow());
    }
});
```

Also, in your `update()` method you will need to update the data of the model in reverse model row order. This way when you do the delete of the rows there is no issue with the indexes being incorrect.

Comment: Hmm, but how this is suppose to help with the fact, that events store information connected with old state of the model. If we receive 3 events like in sample above, then all of these TableModelEvents will have already set colIndex,rowIndex, and due to sequence nature of processing of these events and modifying model, when processing second event, colIndex, and rowIndex will be already inconsistent with the model.

Comment: f we receive 3 events like in sample above (imagine someone would call update(new int[] {1,3,5}, "DELETE ME"), then all of TableModelEvents generated by fireCellUpdated will be processed sequentially. Invoking later one removal will not change the fact, that second and third removal will use bad row and column indices, propagated as a part of TableModelEvent

Comment: @MateuszFryc Sorry, I wasn't paying attention to the fact that you were deleting multiple rows at once. The problem is that your update() method contains an array of model row indexes. These indexes will always be wrong once you delete the first row. What you really want to do is update the data of the model in reverse model row order. This way when you do the delete of the rows there is no issue with the indexes being incorrect. You would still want to update the model in reverse model row order even if you decide to add the code to the TableModel itself.

Comment: yeah right, updating in reverse order should do the work, that is actually what I am doing in some other table model, when deleting sequentially data from model, thanks.

Comment: @MateuszFryc, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept' the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: you should edit an answer then, as current answer do not address the problem properly.